# Why IIS filter out HTTP POST requests send using raw TCP socket and closed right after write

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api, tcp

I'm traying to send many short independent http POST requests to simple .NET webapi app. Requests are created in loop and each of them is sended using new TCP connection. Whats important here each http request only writes to server without waiting for any response. So loop is based on operations:

- create request
- open socket
- write request
- close socket

In such scenerio webapi app (ASP.NET MVC 5.2.7) hosted on IIS 10 does not receive any of incoming requests. Control is never transferred to corresponding method in ApiController. I've notice that additional sleep (ex 100ms) added between socket write and close eliminates problem. But minimazing sleep length causes increase number of missing requests. Also waiting for socket read (response) is a fix. But its not satisfying. I cannot wait for server response or add additional delay. 
Whats interesting here pile of created requests is not a problem. Even one request created in such manner does not appear in the other side.

What could be a reason of such behavior?

I've tested similar webapi app in ASP.NET Core 2.1. Kestrel handles all requests as it should. Also sending these request to simple TcpListener server works.

Comment: I guess IIS detects premature closing of the socket. If your issue with this is the delay, only, then you can try to use async/await.

Comment: Windows socket API might consider you are performing DDOS attack with those short-live TCP connections.

Comment: According to tests with kestrel and tcplistener I think its not a socket limit but rather IIS feature. Maybe it can be controlled.